# Is it possible to display a DIV to not logged in users and then change it for users who are logged in?

Tags: php, functions, content

Basically I'm putting together a magazine site that wants a strong focal point on the homepage for users who haven't signed up, if the user is logged in we need this content to show something else, is this possible?

Basically I need a function to show X if the user is logged in and if not to show Y, the code will be placed in the header so whatever page the user has landed on it will encourage the viewer to register for an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, just use the **is_user_logged_in()** function as [descibed in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) for this.

It would go like this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "you are logged."; } else { echo "You are not logged"; } ?>
```

Comment: Can you echo the users name with that code?  Also the message for not logged in users will need to contain a login form, is that possible?

Comment: You can use the get currentuserinfo() function to retrieve infos about the user currently viewing the page: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Yes you can add anything in the else{} statement. You can close the php tag right after the '{' and put as much html as you want.

Comment: Is it safe to say that the following code would do the job? 

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/welcome.php'); } else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/register.php'); } ?>

Comment: Best way to know is trying.